# Filter object key by on comparing values under different keys

Tags: javascript

I would like to filter results such that when I compare the value under Score with the value under against, I return the winning team

Using this as an example

```
const newData = [
    {"Year": 1,
    "Score": 3,
    "Against": 5,
    "GameID": 2,
    "Team": 'A' },
    {"Year": 1,
    "Score": 5,
    "Against": 3,
    "GameID": 2,
    "Team": 'B' }
]
```

My desired output would be `['B']`

This is what I have tried

```
const newArr = newData.filter(element => element.Score > element.Against)
console.log(newArr.Team)
```

This returns `undefined`

Comment: Try replacing `console.log(newArr.Team)` with `console.log(newArr.map(o => o.Team));`

Answer (score 1):

`newArr` is an array, and the property `Team` does not relate to it, but to its elements. You can use `map` to convert the array of objects to an array of team name(s):

```js
const newData = [{"Year": 1,"Score": 3,"Against": 5,"GameID": 2,"Team": 'A'},{"Year": 1,"Score": 5,"Against": 3,"GameID": 2,"Team": 'B'}]

const newArr = newData.filter(element => element.Score > element.Against)
                      .map(element => element.Team);
console.log(newArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this as resault:

[image]

You can do it by accessing `newArr[0].Team`

```
const newData = [
    {"Year": 1,
    "Score": 3,
    "Against": 5,
    "GameID": 2,
    "Team": 'A' },
    {"Year": 1,
    "Score": 5,
    "Against": 3,
    "GameID": 2,
    "Team": 'B' }
]
```

```
const newArr = newData.filter(element => element.Score > element.Against)
console.log(newArr[0].Team)
```

And it will print `B`

Comment: Would this work if the array contains more than 1 element?

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand the question and your intentions, can you give me an example and expected result?